# Storing data to decimal data type in mysql

Tags: php, string, operators

```
$id = $_POST["id"]; 
$prevread = $_POST["prev"];                 
$presread = $_POST["pres"];

$getPrev = (int)$prevread;
$getPres = (int)$presread;

$totalcons = (int)$_POST[$getPres - $getPrev];

$sql = "UPDATE con_billing SET totalConsumed ='$totalcons' WHERE con_id='$id';
```

Comment: I cant store the data from $totalcons to my database table con_billing in totalConsumed.. What seems the problem ??

Comment: ok, than what do u need??

Comment: Well `(int)$_POST[$getPres - $getPrev];` that's something you don't see every day.

Comment: should be `$totalcons = (int) $getPres - $getPrev;`

Comment: is my operation had a problem in saving the data i want ? i cant get the difference in my $totalcons

Comment: Problem Solved sir ! Thanks a lot.